# Is it possible to evaluate the value of x+z?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$a\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 6 \\
     1 & 4
  \end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    x & 27 \\
     y & z
  \end{bmatrix}$$
Is it possible to evaluate the value of x+z?

I can see in this math that there are three known variables, but If I am asked to find a numeric value of x+z then how to do it?

Any suggestion?

Comment: There seem to be four variables in that problem:  $a,x,y$ and $z$.  Unless $a$ is not meant to represent a scalar?

Comment: what does $a$ mean?

Comment: Sorry yes four variables. What I assumed first that,, I could find it  easily considering simple matrix manipulation but I couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've written, it looks like you have four equations in four variables:

1. $2a = x$
2. $6a = 27$
3. $a = y$
4. $4a = z$

Solve the system!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a\times 6=27$ which implies that $a=\frac{27}{6}$ and $y=a=\frac{27}{6}$. Moreover, $x+z= a(2+4)=\frac{27}{6}\times 6=27$.